# How to play m3u8 audio file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, m3u8

I have a URL (http://ms1.clickhere2.com:1935/live/power98/playlist.m3u8) and wanted to play in iPhone, with m3u8 format, would somebody help on this, I have used MPMEDIAPLAYER framework and other things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715015/streaming-to-iphone-via-m3u8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
NSString *path =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://stream.alayam.com/alayam/alayam/playlist.m3u8"];



NSURL *audioUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:path];

MPMoviePlayerController *player =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:audioUrl];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(loadStateDidChange:)                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:player];
if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
{
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly];
    [player setFullscreen:YES];
    [player prepareToPlay];
}
```

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController depreciated in iOS10 use AVFoundation instead.