# iPhone : Can't streaming m3u8 url with AudioStreamer

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming, audiostreamer, m3u8

I'm using *Matt Gallagher's* **AudioStreamer** to perform audio streaming in app, the `URL`is coming from server, right now its of type `.m3u8` format, and the problem is ON, before it was of `.mp3`type and streamed normally. It showing an error "No audio data found". However I tried to play `URL` in **Safari** browser in simulator and its playing good so there's no problem with the `URL`.

I've been searching long in google but it was ended with these two SO questions. [Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922700/how-to-play-m3u8-audio-file), [Question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715015/streaming-to-iphone-via-m3u8), but none of having the answer of it yes one has solution to play it using `MPMoviePlayerController` but I want to stream the same with the same I've.

So I dig into code of **AudioStreamer** .h and .m files, where I get to know that the logic of file type selection is at #line no. 555

```
 + (AudioFileTypeID)hintForFileExtension:(NSString *)fileExtension { .... }
```

an `AudioFileTypeID` need to return there, the list is defined in `AudioFile.h` of `AudioToolbox.framework` doesn't contains `.m3u8` file type so I can't return it here (I tried for patching with different types there).

I tried to find any alternative types (which can  be use instead of this) but no results I get. Then I gone through [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html), and [Issues Discussion](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues/43) but none of helped me!

P.S. I've checked `AudioToolbox.framework` in `iOS6.0.` to check for the availability of file type but it doesn't exist at all.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with mpmovieviewcontroller. I am also using it for playing streaming audio in one of my Apps. For streaming type content (Like audio/video from web services or from internet) then it is perfect player. And it also look like iPhone default player. Search some tutorial on it & implement it. It is easily be implemented also.

Comment: Thanks for the response Vishal, as I've said in question that `MPMoviePlayerController` can be an alternative for that. But I'm looking for the soln. within `AudioStreamer`, lets rest on SO! :)

Comment: Dude honestly speaking I am also stuck at this point then I am also try to implement AudioStreamer but not succeeded then I am try with mpmovieviewcontroller.If you succeeded in this way then it is really appreciated.